# Saving integer input into a list in (swi-)prolog

Tags: prolog

How do I create a list with n entries and fill it with integers from the user input?

Example:

```
write('How long should the list be?'), nl.
```

- user enters a number n

`write('Enter n integers. Press ENTER after each integer.'), nl.`

- user enters n integers

Answer (score 1):

I do not quite get why you need to do actual I/O (at this point).

If possible, try to stick to using the [prolog-toplevel](/questions/tagged/prolog-toplevel). It can save you a lot of trouble / time / effort during the development phase of the "relational core" of the problem you want to tackle.

Comment: Well, writing your own input and output a couple of times is maybe one path to appreciating what the top level gives you for free.

Comment: For a long time, REPL was a kind of divide between the static and the dynamic, the interpreted and the compiled etc. Today, the OOP mainstream has come to appreciate REPL (cf. www.mono-project.com/docs/tools+libraries/tools/repl/), it is common ground and accepted as good practise. Not necessarily a tool that fits every problem, but a tool that fits certain kinds of problems to a T!